# OSGI embedding a bundle into the Karaf container instead of individual modules?

Tags: java, osgi, karaf

I'm using OSGI/Karaf ecosystem. Initially, I was embedding the same jar into two different bundles. The fact that the two bundles share data utilizing classes from this embedded jar, I'm getting class-cast exceptions. Assuming this is from the fact that two different instances of the same jar are being embedded. (`Classloader` issue?).

My idea is to just install this into the container and have the bundles use it. I'm having two issues, first is that this jar isn't a bundle, the second problem is.. I found a service mix version of this jar and I'm getting the following error:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: No native code clauses found in the value of Bundle-NativeCode: *

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if two bundles use the same "dependency" declare those dependencies via Import-Package instead of embedding the jar. 
Second, if you want to have a list of bundles installed in one go, use the features Apache Karaf is providing. 
See documentation [here](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_feature_bundles), or a simple example:

```
<feature name="my-project" version="1.0.0">
  <feature>other</feature>
  <bundle start-level="80" start="false">mvn:com.mycompany.myproject/myproject-dao</bundle>
  <bundle start-level="85" start="false">mvn:com.mycompany.myproject/myproject-service</bundle>
</feature>
```

Another way is to simply install the dependency bundle itself via:

```
bundle:install mvn:com.mycompany.myproject/myproject-dao
```